# Tool for generating mathematical billiards

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, math-software, billiards

i'm currently looking for some program which can generate arbitrary mathematical billiards and trajectories inside them. Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks/ Mats

Comment: This is not a good question for this site, in my oppinion. It's like saying I want to go to the moon, does anyone have any help. What do you need help with? Programming, physics, mathematics, numerics, there's a whole load of knowledge one needs for this type of thing...

Comment: I was asking if there were any existing program, sorry if you got offended.

Comment: If you would like help on the motions and collisions, contact me at: Boxholder
Tamms, IL 62988-0401

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried asking our friend Google?

Anyway, my search returns in the top five result [this MATLAB script](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10692-billiard-simulator) which looks fairly promising.

If you need help programming something like this, I would suggest looking into programming help on *ray tracing*, since the mathematics of tracing a billiard trajectory is basically the same.

Comment: Actually i did a search but clearly i was blind. Thanks for the answer!